# Node.js mysql pool issue

Tags: mysql, node.js

I've started to use pool connection to mysql, instead of using normal connection with *Node.js*. Because I need to release connection after process has finish. When connection keeps open, *Node.js* getting in exception due to *mysql* timeout issue.

I've edited my code and not it gives me error like that in Line 94:

```
TypeError: Object #<Connection> has no method 'release'
    at Query._callback (/usr/local/src/conn.js:94:28)
```

Above that line :

```
socket.on('getUnreadPM', function (msg) {


    var userSocket = clients[msg.userDestID];

    if (msg.lastGotMessage == 'none') {
        post = 'Select * from messages where (destUserID=\'' + msg.userDestID + '\' AND srcUserID=\'' + msg.userSrcID + '\') OR (destUserID=\'' + msg.userSrcID + '\' AND srcUserID=\'' + msg.userDestID + '\')';

    } else {

        post = 'Select * from messages where destUserID=\'' + msg.userDestID + '\' AND srcUserID= \'' + msg.userSrcID + '\' AND messageSendDate between \'' + msg.lastGotMessage + '\' and \'' + msg.deviceCurrentTime + '\' AND messageSendDate > \'' + msg.lastGotMessage + '\' order by messageSendDate';

    }

    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        // Use the connection   
        connection.query(post, function (error, results, fields) {
            // And done with the connection.

            if (results.length > 0) {

                if (typeof userSocket !== 'undefined') {

                    var boolData = results[0];
                    //console.log('bool data lenght : ',results.length);
                    var messageID = new Array();
                    var srcUserID = new Array();
                    var destUserID = new Array();
                    var messageContent = new Array();
                    var messageDate = new Array();
                    var didRead = new Array();

                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)

                    {
                        messageID.push(results[i].messageID);
                        srcUserID.push(results[i].srcUserID);
                        destUserID.push(results[i].destUserID);
                        messageContent.push(results[i].messageContent);
                        messageDate.push(dateFormat(results[i].messageSendDate, "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss"));
                        didRead.push(results[i].didRead);
                    }

                    userSocket.emit('history :', {
                        'dataMode': 'history',
                            'srcUserID': srcUserID,
                            'destUserID': destUserID,
                            'messageContent': messageContent,
                            'messageSendDate': messageDate,
                            'didread': didRead
                    });

                } else {

                    userSocket.emit('history :', {
                        'dataMode': 'none',

                    });
                }

            } else {

                userSocket.emit('history :', {
                    'dataMode': 'none',

                });                

            }

            connection.release();

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I've solved my issue with simply putting connection.end(); after each node-mysql function...

Answer (score 0):

The mysql connection has no release method. So you can't release it.

I've written such a node module for my application a few months ago, you can find it here: https://github.com/LinuxDoku/node-mysql-pool

It creates an pool of connections at startup, queues your queries and sends them successive to the database. After getting the result, the connection will be released for new queries.

Comment: I've just used to Pools method . Is there any problem about mysql driver that i got with Npm  ?

Comment: Which mysql driver are you using?